# QScopedArrayPointer guarding my data but it is still leaking

Tags: c++, qt, memory-leaks, smart-pointers

```
#include <QScopedArrayPointer>
#include <QDebug>
#include <stdexcept>

class MyData{
public:
  MyData() {
    qDebug() << "Construct a data";
  }

  ~MyData() {
    qDebug() << "Delete a data";
  }

private:
  float internal_data_;
};

class MyClass{
  QScopedArrayPointer<MyData> data_;
public:
  MyClass(){
    data_.reset(new MyData[10]);

    throw std::runtime_error("Shit happens");
  }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    MyClass a_class;

    return 1;
}
```

Running this program will output:

```
Construct a data 
Construct a data 
Construct a data 
Construct a data 
Construct a data 
Construct a data 
Construct a data 
Construct a data 
Construct a data 
Construct a data 
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  Shit happens
The program has unexpectedly finished.
```

Right before the runtime_error, the variable data_ has been fully created. Why is it that data_ destructor not called?

Also, how do I make sure memory does not leak in this case?

Comment: What are you expecting? The destructor isn't being called because the `std::runtime_error` is not being caught.

Comment: I was hoping that since data_ construction is done, its destructor will be called automatically. How do I make sure allocated data is freed when an exception happens?

Comment: If you throw a concrete exception from the constructor your scoped array may still have a reference. Ideally you would want to catch this exception and handle it rather than unwinding to an abort.

Comment: Actually my first comment was wrong, sorry. The problem is that you're throwing from a constructor. When you throw from a constructor, the object is not fully constructed, so it's destructor won't be called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is that your exception is uncaught and is being handled by the terminate handler. Since there is no `catch` to handle the exception, there is no way for the compiler to know how much to "unroll". If you catch the exception, then destruction occurs. You can then of course re-throw it if you like, for example:

```
#include <QScopedArrayPointer>
#include <QDebug>
#include <stdexcept>

class MyData{
public:
  MyData() {
    qDebug() << "Construct a data";
  }

  ~MyData() {
    qDebug() << "Delete a data";
  }

private:
  float internal_data_;
};

class MyClass{
  QScopedArrayPointer<MyData> data_;
public:
  MyClass(){
    data_.reset(new MyData[10]);

    throw std::runtime_error("Shit happens");
  }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    try {
        MyClass a_class;
    } catch (const std::runtime_error &) {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Outputs the following:

```
$ ./test2 
Construct a data 
Construct a data 
Construct a data                                                                                                                     
Construct a data                                                                                                                     
Construct a data                                                                                                                     
Construct a data                                                                                                                     
Construct a data 
Construct a data 
Construct a data 
Construct a data 
Delete a data 
Delete a data 
Delete a data 
Delete a data 
Delete a data 
Delete a data 
Delete a data 
Delete a data 
Delete a data 
Delete a data 
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  Shit happens
Aborted
```